# Determine if listview multiple item checkbox is checked

Tags: vb.net

I have a list view with check box. I want to make the button visible, if item in `listView` is checked. If there's no checked item `visible = false`.

Comment: thank you anyway ill figure out a solution but if you have a better explanation please don't hesitate to add another answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another quick example...

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    ListView1_ItemChecked(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
    Button1.Visible = (ListView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub MOOElv_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles MOOElv.ItemChecked
    Dim iCount As Integer

    For i = 0 To MOOElv.Items.Count - 1
        If MOOElv.Items(i).Checked = True Then
            iCount = 1
        End If
        If iCount >= 1 Then
            consumebtn.Visible = True
        Else
            consumebtn.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

> Thank you i got my own solution i just put a loop inside an event handler, then first determine the amount of items and if checked the button will visible :D